# Not Getting returned Obj from Functional Interface while using Stream

Tags: java, json, java-8, java-stream

I used the stream API to iterate and perform some actions on JSONArray of JSONObjects and Functional Interface:

```
    public void getValues(JSONObject obj){
        if(obj!=null && obj.containsKey("value")){
            JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) obj.get("value");
        
            if(jsonArray!=null){
                jsonArray.stream().map(getValue).forEach((item) -> {
                    // this item should be of FinalJSONValues obj but here i am getting generic type.
                    item.getAllValues()
                });
            }   
        }
    }
    
    private Function<JSONObject, FinalJSONValues> getValue = (obj) -> {
        FinalJSONValues finalValues = null;
        try {
            finalValues = new FinalJSONValues(obj,this.values);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return finalValues;
    };
```

In this code, JSONArray values are streamed and Functional Interface applied for each JSONObject which returns FinalJSONValues obj. In the foreach of stream **item** should be FinalJSONValues object, but i am getting this warning message **Type safety: The method forEach(Consumer) belongs to the raw type Stream. References to generic type Stream should be parameterized**
Am I missing something here?

Comment: What generic type ARE you getting? Some early versions of Java8 had issues with the resolution of lambda generics. Try to install at least build 171, but rather the newest Java8 version.

Comment: What JSON library are you using? All the dang JSON libraries have types named `JSONArray` or `JsonArray`, and they all have different methods. We shouldn't have to go search through them all to figure out which one(s) have an API that is consistent with your code.

Comment: Why do you believe that a `JSONArray` can produce a `Stream<JSONObject>`? What if the array contained strings or numbers?

Comment: I am using org.json.simple library and getting this error message "Type safety: The method forEach(Consumer) belongs to the raw type Stream. References to generic type Stream should be parameterized" instead of FinalJSONValues Object.
@TreffnonX

Comment: This JSONArray only contains JSONObjects, it won't contain strings and numbers
@Andreas

Comment: @DAK Java is static typed, so the compiler will validate the code for what *could* happen, not for what actually happens. Since a JSON array can contain a mix of objects, strings, numbers, booleans, and nulls, the Java compiler will basically think that anything can be in an array, not just `JSONObject` objects. --- *FYI:* The warning means that you get a `Stream`, which is basically a `Stream<Object>`, not a `Stream<JSONObject>`, so the mapping method is not compatible.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for sharing this. Then what will be an effective method for iterating and do actions on individual objects?, like forloop, foreach

Comment: Have the `getValue` lambda take an `Object`, then cast to `JSONObject` inside the lambda.

Comment: In that place, I got JSONObject as expected.  the problem here is not getting return type of functional interface "FinalJSONValues" @Andreas